# pynids (nids) import error using python3

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-import

I have installed pynids (pynids-0.6.3) on a Raspberry Pi v.2 running Jessie Light from https://bitbucket.org/jmichel/pynids in directory /usr/local/share/pynids-0.6.3 as follows: 
`

```
cd /usr/local/share/pynids-0.6.3 
python3 setup.py build 
python3 setup.py install
python  setup.py install `
```

The installation went ok for both python2 and python3 as far as I can tell:

```
~> pip show pynids
---
Name: pynids
Version: 0.6.3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:

~> pip3 show pynids
---
Name: pynids
Version: 0.6.3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires:
```

The nids modules are located where I think they should:

```
~> find /usr/local/lib -name nids*
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nidsmodule.cpython-34m.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nidsmodule.so
```

Importing nids in python2 also works fine:

```
~> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nids
>>>
```

But when trying to import nids in python3 I get an import error saying there is no nids module:

```
~> python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nids
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'nids'
>>>
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! It was a bug in setup.py

In setup.py in /usr/local/share/pynids-0.6.3 the name/text "nidsmodule" were changed to "nids". Now import works also in Python3.

```
        ext_modules = [ Extension(
                        "nids",
                        #"nidsmodule",
                        define_macros = [
                            #("DEBUG", None),
                            #("ENABLE_TCPREASM_DEBUG", None),
                            ("ENABLE_TCPREASM", None),
                        ],
                        sources=["nidsmodule.c"],
                        include_dirs = INCLUDE_DIRS,
                        libraries = ["pcap", "net", "glib-2.0", "gthread-2.0"],
                        library_dirs = LIBRARY_DIRS,
                        extra_objects = EXTRA_OBJECTS
                    ) 
                  ],
    url = "https://bitbucket.org/jmichel/pynids"
    )
```